# Org で gantt-chart view のようなことがやりたい

Tags: emacs

org-mode の各項目を、 gantt チャート状にして表示して、そこからキー操作でスケジュールを変更できるような elisp パッケージはありますか。

最低限、次のようなキー操作があったらいいなと思っています。

- 始端・終端のみをずらす
- 日数は変えずに、行う期間をシフトする

Comment: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/22390/9371 にも投稿しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

emacs.s.c でも回答があるように、 [TaskJuggler](http://taskjuggler.org/) くらいしか見たことがありません。TaskJuggler をつかっても、チャートの上から修正することはできないので、望んでいることをそのまま実行できるパッケージは今のところ無いかも？